# Aggregate list dataframe in pandas using dedicated function

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, aggregate

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```py
data = {'ID_1': {0: '10A00', 1: '10B00', 2: '20001', 3: '20001'},
        'ID_2_LIST': {0: [20009, 30006], 1: [20001, 30006],
                      2: [30009, 30006], 3: [20001, 30003]},
        'ID_OCCURRENCY_LIST': {0: [1, 2], 1: [5, 6], 2: [2, 4], 3: [1, 3]}}

# create df
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

|    | ID_1   | ID_2_LIST      | ID_OCCURRENCY_LIST   |
|---:|:-------|:---------------|:---------------------|
|  0 | 10A00  | [20009, 30006] | [1, 2]               |
|  1 | 10B00  | [20001, 30006] | [5, 6]               |
|  2 | 20001  | [30009, 30006] | [2, 4]               |
|  3 | 20001  | [20001, 30003] | [1, 3]               |
```

I would aggregate by **ID_1** field applying an external function (in order to identify similar ID_1, let's say "similarID(ID1,ID2)", which returns ID1 or ID2 according to some internal rules), re-generate the list of ID2 and sum the occurrencies for all the equal ID2.

The outcome should be:

```
  **INDEX    ID_1      ID_2_LIST              ID_OCCURRENCY_LIST**
   0      10A00      [20009,30006,20001]            [1, 8, 5]
   1      10B00      [20001,30006, 30003,20001]     [5, 6, 4, 2]
   1      20001      [30009,30006, 20001,30003]     [2, 4, 1, 3]
```

***EDIT***
The code for the function is the following(s1=first string,c1=second string, p1=similarity percentage l1=confidence level, demeraulevenshtein is a literature function):

```
def pySimilar(s1,c1,p1,l1): 
  if s1 is None or c1 is None:
    return 0
  if len(s1)<=5 or len(c1)<=5:
    return 0

  s1=s1.strip()
  c1=c1.strip()
  s=s1
  c=c1
  if s1[3:len(s1)]==c1[3:len(c1)]:
      return 1

  if len(s1)>=len(c1):
    ITERATIONLENGTH=len(c1)/2
  else:
    ITERATIONLENGTH=len(s1)/2

  if len(s1)>=len(c1):
      a=int(len(c1)/2)+1
      if s1.find(c1[3:a])<0:
        return 0  
  else:
      b=int(len(s1)/2)+1
      if c1.find(s1[3:b])<0:
        return 0

  v=[]

  CNT=0
  TMP=0
  max_res=0
  search=s1
  while CNT < ITERATIONLENGTH:
    TMP=(100-((pyDamerauLevenschtein(s[3:len(s)],c[3:len(c)]))*100)/(len(c)-3)) * ((len(search)-3)/(len(s1)-3))
    v.append(TMP)
    CNT=CNT+1
    if TMP>max_res:
        max_res = TMP
    #s=s[0:len(s)-CNT]
    search=s1[0:len(s1)-CNT]
    s=s1[0:len(s1)-CNT]
    c=c1[0:len(c1)-CNT]


  if ((p1-(l1*p1/100)<=sum(v)/len(v) and sum(v)/len(v)<=p1+(l1*p1/100)) or sum(v)/len(v)>=p1+(l1*p1/100)) :
    return 1
  else:
    return 0
```

I have implemented a function to be applied in the dataframe but it is very slow:

```
def aggregateListAndOccurrencies(list1,list2):
  final = []
  final_cnt = []
  output = []
  cnt_temp = 0
  while list1:
    elem = list1.pop(0)
    cnt = list2.pop(0)
    i=0
    cnt_temp = cnt
    for item in list1:  
      if pyMATCHSIMILARPN(elem,item,65,20)==1:
        cnt_temp = list2[i]+cnt_temp
        list1.pop(i)
        list2.pop(i)
      i+=1
    final.append(elem)
    final_cnt.append(cnt_temp)

  output.append(final)
  output.append(final_cnt)
  return output
```

How could apply this in pandas? Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to be more specific. "some internal rules" isn't enough to work with

Comment: the function to be used for aggregation is a similarity function which gets two strings and returns 1 if the two strings are similar, 0 otherwise. obviously I can modify the function returning null if they are not similar, or one of the two strings if they are similar

Comment: have you written that function? are you asking for help to write that function?

Comment: yes the function is already written. Now the scope is to use that function during aggregation, but I don't know if it is sufficient to return a part number in case of similarity and NaN in case of not similarity.

Comment: The function has the following definition:

pyMATCHSIMILARPN(string1,string2)

and returns 1 is string1 is similar to string 2, 0 if otherwise

Comment: can you just copy & past that function into the question. any answer anyone gives you will be pure speculation without a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do a groupby over your **ID_1** and just sum the **ID_2_List** and **ID_OCCURRENCY_LIST** columns:

```
df.groupby('ID_1').agg({'ID_2_LIST': 'sum', 'ID_OCCURRENCY_LIST': 'sum'})
```

if there's a spicific function you'd like the groupby to work with you can then you can use `lambda` to add it in the .agg:

```
df.groupby('ID_1').agg({'ID_2_LIST': 'sum', 'ID_OCCURRENCY_LIST': lambda x: ' '.join(x)})
```